Flexible box image `height: 100%` Safari
Given a flexible box with two children each at 50%, if an image is included inside one of the children with height: 100%, it consumes far more than desired in Safari.

<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='first'></div>
  <div class="second">
    <img src="https://pixy.org/src/465/4654979.jpg"
  </div>
</div>

codepen
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.first {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.second {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


try height: 0;min-height:100% instead of height: 100%

try adding display: flex to .second
